# UICollectionView inside UITableViewCell: order of `reloadData` for each?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview, nslayoutconstraint

I have a `UICollectionView` inside a `UITableViewCell`, the constraints are that the collection view fits the cell's boundary.

Depending on some external data (that regularly refreshes), I create different collection view cells (small and large), and they have different heights.

When I got external data, I reload the collection view and the table view in order:

1. reload collection view for the new cells for external data
2. reload table view for the new height for that particular row

The problem is, if say, I got some data that requires **small** collection view cell, the table view cell's height would be **small**, then if new data comes in which requires large collection view cell, at step 1, the collection view is still in **small** size but the cell inside it would be **large**, then I got this warning:

> the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and bottom values.

It works fine if I got data for large cell, then new data for small cell.

So what should be the right way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: @iphonic The OP has a UICollectionView inside a UITableViewCell, not the other way around.

Comment: When you need to reload collection view with different cell size, the order of updating UI should be  1. Without auto layout    - Table view "reload rows" with row index having collection view to be updated and return respective row height   - Reload collection view. 2. With auto layout:    - Update collection view hight constraint    - Reload collection view

Answer (score 0):

Have you set this on viewDidLoad?

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = CGFloat(60.0) //your best height estimate
```

Comment: I thought about this actually, but the automatic size would require the table cell's content (ie. collection view in my case) to have an intrinsic content size, but the collection view (ie. scroll view) has a strange behaviour regarding intrinsic content size.

Comment: Otherwise you can store the height on a property and call: `tableView.beginUpdates()` `tableView.endUpdates()`. That would trigger the height change without reloading the data.

Comment: Thanks @pesch let me try